# not getting any notification in fencing using android

Tags: android, android-geofence

i am trying to run a sample of fencing in android. i am showing a fence with a radius of 2 meter on a google map and at the same time i am showing my current location with 2 meter radius.

as you can see in a below image that my current location ( in green ) is far from the fence ( in red ) but still neither my `Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT` nor `IntentService` is not getting called.

even when i get entered into the fence nothing gets notified.

[image]

i have seen other threads but nothing is getting worked.

here are my basic settings

```
<service
            android:name=".GeofenceTransitionsIntentService"
            android:exported="false"
          >
        </service>
```

pending intent

```
 private PendingIntent getGeofenceTransitionPendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

inside onConnected

```
mGeofenceRequestIntent = getGeofenceTransitionPendingIntent();

LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(mApiClient, mGeofenceList,
                mGeofenceRequestIntent);
```

i tried it with a BroadcastReceiver but no luck

```
 private PendingIntent getmGeofenceTransitionPendingIntentReceiver(){

        if(mGeofenceRequestIntent!=null){

            return mGeofenceRequestIntent;
        }else{


            Intent intent = new Intent(GEOFENCE_RECEIVER);
            return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        }
    }
```

inside my manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".GeofenceReceiver"  android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.geofence.georeceiver"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: you're testing on emulator?

Comment: and 2 meter geofence is way too little, I'd go 200m otherwise it may never get triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current radius should be less than the radius of the geofence. The ENTERED event only triggers once your entire "radius circle" is inside that of the geofence.

Also 2m for a geofence is very small, and I would suggest at the very least ±10m.